# Can a Silverlight video player play a wmv from an Azure blob?

Tags: silverlight, video, azure

Here is a simple scenario:

An Azure blob contains a wmv video. The blob is public. When I point my browser to the blob, Windows Media Player starts and starts streaming the video.

However, if I point a Silverlight MediaElement to the same URL, it does not play anything.

Why would that be?

Comment: Can you provide a URL to this blob?

Comment: crossdomain issues or encoding

Comment: Probably not a cross-domain issue. (There's no same-origin policy applied to media in Silverlight... it can come from anywhere.) I'd guess encoding or perhaps content-type. But if you provide a URL to the blob, I'm sure someone will figure it out. (Typically, yes, this will work fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Launch a tool (like one from Cerebrata or any other) that let's you view the content type of the media stored in Azure blob storage.

My guess is that the content type is blank in Azure blob storage and the Silverlight MediaElement doesn't know what to do with it.